# How do industrial researchers get access to online journals?

Tags: publications, industry, online-publication, online-resource

When one is hired by industry to research (or something of innovative nature), he or she may want (or need) to access online journal articles.
But I suppose normal industrial jobs (e.g. software engineer in Amazon) don't grant online subscriptions to journals (like, access to a network IP with a subscription, just like many university accounts).
So, do industrial researchers purchase subscriptions themselves (this seems to be close to impossible)? Or do they apply for subscriptions through their company?
I have not worked in the industry, but I am curious.

Comment: Visit your local university library. The bigger the better of course.

Comment: If that journal is essential for the job they hired you to do, then that company should get you access to it.  On the other hand, what journals are available to workers at that company may be something to ask them when they are recruiting you, and maybe you will take the answer into account in deciding which job offer to accept.

Comment: I don't know exactly how many online journals my employers subscribe to, but the company (in the UK) used to run its own library (with more than one librarian, plus several assistants) and subscribe to maybe 30 or 40 print journals - and kept decades of copies of them in storage. If that's what you *need* to operate, you pay to have it! Technical books were also available through interlibrary loans, of course...

Comment: I use `sci-hub.bz`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But I suppose normal industrial jobs (e.g. software engineer in Amazon) don't grant online subscription to journal (like, access to a network IP with subscription, just like many university accounts).

Some industry research labs do subscribe to digital libraries, though in my experience, not as many as a university. For example, in the industry research lab where I'm currently spending my summer, I can access the ACM digital library, but not Elsevier journals.

To access papers that are not available by subscription, researchers in industry usually try one of the methods described in the answers to these questions:

- [What do you do when you find yourselves with an unreadable/inaccessible paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/what-do-you-do-when-you-find-yourselves-with-an-unreadable-inaccessible-paper)
- [Access to journals for individuals outside of an institution?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/access-to-journals-for-individuals-outside-of-an-institution)
- [Ways to get free and legal access to research papers as a researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51923/ways-to-get-free-and-legal-access-to-research-papers-as-a-researcher)

Answer (score 4):

It is often possible to get a library card from your university library.  Someone will have to pay for it - presumably your employer - but I can't imagine that if access is essential to your work lack of access would be a longer term issue.

(Some schools also allow some form of access for alumni, usually at a discount over regular paying non-university members.)

Comment: exactly some universities , have a fee based subscription to research databases , and by paying that yearly fee , or monthly , sometimes daily unique one usage tickets you get access to the journals, also one can contact research paper author to share if he is willing the information , if its subject related.