# Accessing scientific research papers post university

Tags: publications, journals

As part of my coping mechanism for leaving university and accepting the inevitable loss of scientific knowledge post university, I am considering subscribing to a scientific journal so that I can continue to learn and not completely lose touch.

However, there is not much on how I should best approach this. How does one chose the best journal? There are many out there and the subscriptions are not that clear on how they work.

I’ve looked online and some websites quote figures of over £1000 a year which is not feasible.

> So what is the best way to access scientific research (i) online and (ii) in hard-copy form as an individual with no affiliation to an institute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to journals for individuals outside of an institution?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/access-to-journals-for-individuals-outside-of-an-institution)

Comment: This is perfect thank you, you may close the question

Comment: You can have a look at Sci-Hub.